# Create IIS Binding Onto Site with IPv6?

Tags: iis-7, dns, ipv6, hostname

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/327/powershell-scripts/

```
CreateIISBindingOntoSite "DAP1Site1" 80 "www.DAP1Site2.com" "http"
```

However I want to generate and usa a IPv6 IP address. My new DNS Managment service allows me to use IPv6 addresses and host names.

Do I need to auto-generate IPv6 IP address first?
How do I  auto-generate a IPv6 IP address? (by code)

*note: I use IIS 7.5*

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to throw away that old script. If you're using IIS7.5 then you'll have the WebAdministration PowerShell module available to you:

> [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471(WS.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee909471%28WS.10%29.aspx)

To load this do:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
```

Have a look at the `New-WebBinding` command:

> [New-WebBinding (Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790567.aspx)

You can find out more about these CmdLet's here:

> [Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx)

With regard to IPv6 addresses you can't just magically make one up. You'll either be allocated a public IP address from your pool or you need to use a [Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) (which is synonymous with RFC1918 private IPv4 addresses).